# What are radio frequencies sensitive to in galaxies?

Tags: radio-astronomy, planetary-science, sky-survey, active-galaxy

Apart from 21cm line studies, radio emissions as well as signatures of different radio sources, do radio frequencies help in the identification of a particular physical structure or presence of some certain specific elements/matter present in the galaxies?
If so, what are they?

Comment: The difference between a planet and a galaxy is immense.  This makes your question slightly oddly phrased.  Do you know about the 21 cm line of Hydrogen?

Comment: Yes, I agree.To answer your question: yes, I am aware about tthe 21cm line

Comment: Jupiter has decameter radio emission from 1 to 40 MHz (300 to ~7.5m wavelength) caused by the planet's magnetic field. Searches for radio emission from exoplanets are underway; a recent (open access) [paper](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2019/04/aa32848-18/aa32848-18.html#S14) conclusions suggests radio emission from exoplanets out to ~20pc may be possible if the exoplanets have mag. field strengths 1-10 million times stronger than Jupiter (as expected for close-in exoplanets). This leaves the vast majority of the galaxy unsearchable for planets in the radio. Q needs some clarity

Comment: "Yes, I agree."  - can you fix your question? I makes no sense to ask about emission from planets and galaxies in the same question.

Comment: I have made the required changes.